# Replace/Override statically linked library

Tags: linux, static-libraries, gnu-toolchain

I have an object file — `foo.so` — provided by a vendor. That object file was statically linked with a publicly available library — `bar_1.0.a`. There is a new version of the library `bar_1.1.a` that fixes a critical bug, but the vendor is not supplying a new version of `foo.so`, so I can't take advantage of the bug fix.

Because I don't have access to the source code to `foo.so`, I cannot recompile against the new version of `bar`. I *do* have access to the source code for `bar`, so I can build that at will. The symbols in `bar` have not changed between 1.0 and 1.1, only some of the implementation.

I would like to know if there is a way to replace/override the statically linked `bar_1.0.a` library in `foo.so` with `bar_1.1.a` without having access to the source code of `foo.so`. Or, if that is not possible, can I somehow force `foo.so` to dynamically link against `bar_1.1.so` even though it is statically linked with `bar_1.0.a`?

I know that there are various `LD_*` environment variables that affect dynamic linking, but I don't believe that will help in this case.

Comment: I believe you are looking for Interception or Swizzling. You shadow all the exports `foo.so` and you get yourself loaded first. You provide an updated routine for the vulnerability. Otherwise, you pass the call into the original `foo.so`. Tools like Valgrind use a similar technique for some systems calls (calls like malloc and free). I think the static library `bar.a` is going to make things especially painful.